# Count factors occurring in group in R

Tags: r, dataframe

This is my data:

```
> head(Kandula_for_n)
                date      dist  date_only
1 2005-05-08 12:00:00  138.5861 2005-05-08
2 2005-05-08 16:00:00 1166.9265 2005-05-08
3 2005-05-08 20:00:00 1270.7149 2005-05-08
6 2005-05-09 08:00:00  233.1971 2005-05-09
7 2005-05-09 12:00:00 1899.9530 2005-05-09
8 2005-05-09 16:00:00  726.8363 2005-05-09
```

I would now like to have an **additional column with the count (n) of the data entries (dist) per day**. For 2005-05-08, this would be n=3 as there are 3 data entries at 12, 16 and 20 o'clock. I have applied the following code which actually gave me want I wanted:

```
ndist <-tapply(1:NROW(Kandula_for_n), Kandula_for_n$date_only, function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

After `ndist<-as.data.frame(ndist)`, I got this:

```
> head(ndist)
           ndist
2005-05-08     3
2005-05-09     4
2005-05-10     6
2005-05-11     4
2005-05-12     6
2005-05-13     6
```

The problem is that the count is together with date_only in one column that is called ndist. But I would need them in two separate columns, one with the count and one with date_only. How can this be done?
I guess its rather simple, but I just don't get it.
I would appreciate if you could give me any thoughts on that.

Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are just the row names. You're good to go:

```
ndist$date = row.names(ndist)
```

EDIT: or `ndist = data.frame(date = names(ndist), ndist)` depending on whether it is already a data frame or not.

Comment: or `data.frame(ndist,date_only=names(ndist),row.names=1:length(ndist))`

Comment: or just leave ID variables as (row)names attributes and just index directly when needed. That's what I usually do.

Comment: Thx, I really got confused by these strange row names.

Answer (score 8):

Simply because I find `tapply()` hard to wrap my brain around, I like using `plyr` for these types of things:

```
## make up some data
## you get better/faster/more answers if you do this bit for us :)
dates <- seq(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date() + 5, by = 1)
Kandula_for_n <- data.frame(date_only = sample( dates + 5, 10, replace=TRUE ) , dist=rnorm(10) )

require(plyr)
ddply(Kandula_for_n, "date_only", function(x) data.frame(x, ndist=nrow(x)) )
```

This will give you something like:

```
    date_only       dist ndist
1  2011-10-30  0.2434168     5
2  2011-10-30 -0.9361780     5
3  2011-10-30  1.4593197     5
4  2011-10-30 -0.1851402     5
5  2011-10-30  0.6652419     5
6  2011-10-31  0.8876420     1
7  2011-11-03  0.5087175     2
8  2011-11-03 -1.0065152     2
9  2011-11-04  0.4236352     2
10 2011-11-04  0.4535686     2
```

the `ddply` line:

`ddply(Kandula_for_n, "date_only", function(x) data.frame(x, ndist=nrow(x)) )`

takes the input data, groups it by the `date.only` field, and for every unique value it applies the anonymous function to the data frame made up of only the records with the same value for `date_only`. My anonymous function simply takes the data.frame `x` and appends a column named `ndist` which is the number of rows in `x`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have stumbled now several times over plyr. I think I will definitely investigate it a bit. And I will definitely try to make up the data from now on...

Answer (score 4):

How about something a bit more simple:

```
as.data.frame(table(unique(Kandula_for_n)$date_only))
```

Comment: this is really way mor simple. thx for that. Good to know that snippet.